# Android - How to start third party app with package name?

Tags: android, package

I am wondering how to start an another app from my app using package name.

I have package name in string format like

```
String pkgName = "com.example.appName";
```

That is why i am unable to fetch class name or any other valuable details from it which i can use to make a proper intent to start an activity.

Any idea how to solve this problem. Please Help!!

Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

well, you don't want to fetch ANY class name. What you want to do is to create an `Intent` out of this package name with `Activity`'s that can be launched (they need to have specific `category`). In a single line, what you need to do is:

```
startActivity(getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.appName"));
```

Check the documentation for [PackageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getLaunchIntentForPackage%28java.lang.String%29). Generally speaking, PackageManager has a lot of interesting methods for launching apps.
[Here is my blog entry](http://datamoil.blogspot.com/2011/04/android-universal-intent-to-start.html) doing exactly that for multiple packages.

Comment: Hey thanks for solving this mystery for me. but when i am trying your solution its giving me NullPointerException. any idea why?

Comment: very nice blog. and i found why it was showing me nullpointerexception because i was trying to open google search widget :P ..well thanks for your help. :)

Comment: hehe, i didn't even make it to look into that NullPointerException and you solved it.

Comment: @ElijahSaounkine  i have successfully started another activity but i want to close my whole app

Comment: @ElijahSaounkine java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity

Comment: don't do it in a single line if package doesn't found . intent will be null