# Launch another application in background android

Tags: android

In my application, i start another application (not activity) with this code :

```
protected void launchApp(String packageName) {
    Intent mIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(
            packageName);
    if (mIntent != null) {
        try {
            startActivity(mIntent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException err) {
            Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "App not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            t.show();
        }
    }
}
```

but i would like this application (launched by packageName) run in background and not disturb the UI.

Is it possible ?

Thanks!

Comment: Depends on the application that you launch. There is no way for you to forcibly I.e. launch a new Skype activity in the background.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer, i wasn't sure if that was possible.

Comment: I've been thinking. It might be possible if you launch the new app and at the same time schedule a launch intent back to your own app using the AlarmManager. Just put 100ms delay on it. A bit of a clutch but it might work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a broadcast receiver in the target app and start it by broadcast.

```java
startActivity(getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.appName"));
```

For further information please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5840699/android-how-to-start-third-party-app-with-package-name).

Comment: ok did you see this link i hope it will help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422758/start-application-knowing-package-name